# Pdo how should I put the files

Tags: php, pdo

This is not really of importance but I am still curious whetever I should put the actual "database file" that contain the Pdo connection in /config folder or /lib folder. Or If I should split the variables to config/ and then the actual database connection in a lib/ folder.

How do you do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I normally don't use PDO, but splitting the variables sounds like the better option because you could lock down your application better with permissions and if you use multiple data connections etc. it just makes it easier.